# Coloring the real plane with a countable number of colors.

Tags: combinatorics, real-numbers, ramsey-theory

We color the real plane with a countable number of colors (each vertex gets a color). Can we always find a rectangle such that all of its vertices have the same color? (the edges of the rectangle need not be paralel to the axis)

If the number of colors is finite then clearly such a rectangle must exist. But I am stumped with this version.

Comment: I'm guessing you just want the four vertices all one colour, not the edges or the interior.  Otherwise an easy counterexample is to colour point $(x,y)$ red if $x^2+y^2$ is rational and blue if $x^2+y^2$ is irrational.

Comment: it should be clearer now

Comment: a hint, there is such thing like a closed monocolor figure but reversed : think about islands. If you want absolutely to build such closed form , embed islands. NB : an island is something surrounded by the same color.

Comment: Possibly an answer [monochromatic rectangles in a countable colouring of the plane](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/273/finding-monochromatic-rectangles-in-a-countable-coloring-of-r2)

Comment: very nice, although that one only coveres rectangles with sides paralel to the axiis

Comment: But the accepted answer there quotes a result: CH holds if and only if the plane can be decomposed into countably many parts none containing 4 different points $a,b,c,d$ such that $\text{dist}(a,b)=\text{dist}(c,d)$.  Note that the four vertices of any rectangle have that property.  So if CH is true, your colouring is possible.

Comment: Oh right, could someone plz answerize that?