# Can a circle be colored by countably many colors such that any four points of the same color are not covered by two parallels?

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, coloring

I recently came across a nice little excercise: Prove that for any coloring of a circle by finitely many colors there is always a set of four points of the same color which is covered by two parallels. I will leave this as a riddle here.

I really wondered what the situation is in the case of countably infinite many colors. I found a solution involving the continuum hypothesis but this still leaves the gap of countably many colors and the opposite of CH being true.

Does anyone have an idea about how to approach this?
If it helps i can provide my solution to the CH-Case, but for the moment i think it would mainlybias the way of thinking.

Comment: This is a related problem. Perhaps the solution described there can help https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1919481/coloring-the-real-plane-with-a-countable-number-of-colors

Comment: I might not fully understand the question, but if I did: take a set of infinite parallel lines (all parallel one to each other). If you colored with a finite number of colors, you will have there parallel lines with the same colors

Comment: @Yorch yeah, this should lead to the solution and although i did not get to read the original sources mentioned in the posts, the theorems themselves basically tell that the countable version is equivalent to the continuum hypothesis. Nice result

Comment: @Shaq not necessarily. Assume Wlog that all the lines are horizontal (if not rotate the circle). If the whole left of the circle is blue and the whole right of the circle is red, then for any two of the parallels you chose exactly two of the intersection points are blue and two are red. (Of course it is easy to chose other parallels in this example, but it proves that your strategy does not work)

Comment: I thought you are coloring edges and not vertexes.. So we look for 4 points with the same color, that yields a parallelogram? at least 2 edges are parallel in the square?

Comment: @Shaq Not necessarily a parallelogram. Only two out of the 4 sides need to be parallel.

Comment: A trapezoid, then.

Comment: I guess. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoid#Etymology_and_trapezium_vs_trapezoid